# How to get dual tones for font awesome in React 5

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

With basic CSS and HTML, and even in AngularJS we could add dual tones to font awesome icons with this code:

```
<div class="fa-3x">
  <i class="fad fa-crow" style="--fa-secondary-opacity: 1.0; --fa-primary-color: dodgerblue; --fa-secondary-color: gold;"></i>
</div
```

How do we achieve the same in ReactJS with the following libraries?

> @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core,
>   @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons,
>   @fortawesome/react-fontawesome,

I need help on the styling part with primary and secondary colors to be specific

What I have tried so far is this:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChartPie} style={{"--faPrimaryColor": "#7efff5","--faSecondaryColor":"#ffcccc"}}/>
```

and this

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChartPie} primaryColor="#7efff5" secondaryColor="#ffcccc" color="#ffcccc"/>
```

but neither helped.

Comment: This might provide some answers: https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/issues/259

Comment: @dmikester1: So they are still using CSS though. hmm...

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChartPie} style={{"--fa-primary-color": "#7efff5","--fa-secondary-color":"#ffcccc"}}/>
```

Comment: Hey, sorry. Old post. I've been using this for a long time now. I'll check and update.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this issue using TypeScript, I was getting the following error with my icon:

### Icon

```
const iconStyle = {
  "--fa-primary-color": colors.red, // colors defined elsewhere
  "--fa-secondary-color": colors.yellow 
}
...

<FontAwesomeIcon
  icon={duotone('rocket-launch')}
  size='5x'
  // line with typescript error
  style={iconStyle}
/>
```

### Error

```
(property) FontAwesomeIconProps.style?: CSSProperties
Type '{ "--fa-primary-color": string; "--fa-secondary-color": string; }' has no properties in common with type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.ts(2559)
index.d.ts(41, 3): The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FontAwesomeIconProps'
```

I worked around this by importing CSSProperties from react

```
import { CSSProperties } from "react";
```

and then casted my style object to CSSProperties

```
style={iconStyle as CSSProperties}
```